# Qt Mac Deployment

Tags: qt

Adding QT Framework into my .app bundle

Im following the documentation on Qt site on Deployment.
I created an app is named HTTPClient.app

I created the Framework folder under the Contents and copied crypto++ and qscintilla and Qt frameworks and it looks like this:

[image]

then i run install_name_tool -id -change

```
DylibFile=libqscintilla2.11.dylib
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile  $ProjectName.app/Contents/Frameworks/$DylibFile
install_name_tool -change $DylibFile @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile $ProjectName.app/Contents/MacOS/$ProjectName
```

and the same for crypto++.  I did the following to the Qt Frameworks

```
DylibFile=QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile  $ProjectName.app/Contents/Frameworks/$DylibFile
install_name_tool -change $DylibFile @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile $ProjectName.app/Contents/MacOS/$ProjectName

DylibFile=QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile  $ProjectName.app/Contents/Frameworks/$DylibFile
install_name_tool -change $DylibFile @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile $ProjectName.app/Contents/MacOS/$ProjectName

DylibFile=QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile  $ProjectName.app/Contents/Frameworks/$DylibFile
install_name_tool -change $DylibFile @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile $ProjectName.app/Contents/MacOS/$ProjectName


DylibFile=QtSql.framework/Versions/5/QtSql
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile  $ProjectName.app/Contents/Frameworks/$DylibFile
install_name_tool -change $DylibFile @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile $ProjectName.app/Contents/MacOS/$ProjectName

DylibFile=QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile  $ProjectName.app/Contents/Frameworks/$DylibFile
install_name_tool -change $DylibFile @executable_path/../Frameworks/$DylibFile $ProjectName.app/Contents/MacOS/$ProjectName
```

Now when I run otool i get the following:

[image]

I get crypto and qscintilla path but shouldnt the Qt framework also follow the same pattern?  Its still pointing to the original path

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save yourself time worrying about how to use `install_name_tool` with Qt Frameworks by using the provided tool **[macdeployqt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html#the-mac-deployment-tool)**, which is located in the bin folder of your Qt installation.

This tool will copy the required Qt libraries and set the paths accordingly. So, assuming you've got the Qt bin folder in your path, all you need to do is call this: -

> macdeployqt HTTPClient.app

Note that it only deals with the Qt Framework, so you must still handle the others yourself.

Comment: Wow this saved me the headache.  Thank you for the information